# Like and unlike in angular js using directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**Html**

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="replycommentbtn ng-binding" 
   ng-click="likeClick(uniqueid)"> Like (63)</a> &nbsp;| &nbsp; 

<a href="javascript:;" class="replycommentbtn ng-binding" 
   ng-click="unlikeClick(uniqueid)"> Unlike (14)</a>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('AlbumlikeFeature',[]).directive('AlbumlikeFeature', ['$filter', '$route', function ($filter, $route) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: 'app/components/album/albumlikefeature.html';           

 scope.likeClick = function (dataid) {      
      var resultlike = dataid
      console.log(resultlike);
      resultlike.Like = resultlike.Like + 1;               
      scope.likeCount = resultlike.Like;
      scope.unlikeCount = resultlike.Unlike;             
 };
```

How can i call my directive module in other controller ?
.I tried like this `<albumlike-feature uniqueid="1" photoid="1"></albumlike-feature>` but no result.

And my requirement is on click like i want to increment the value and like unlike same want to increment the value.How can i achieve this ?

`Like(1)`...want to increment the count value in like and same as unlike.

Im getting this error while clicking like button

```
ReferenceError: likeCount is not defined
    at Scope.scope.likeClick (albumlikefeature.js:15)
    at Parser.functionCall (angular.js:10795)
    at angular.js:19036
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12632)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12730)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:19035)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.n.event.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.n.event.add.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Comment: `How can i call my directive module in other controller ?` No you can't call a directive inside controller. Directive names must follow camelCase and so it must be `albumlikeFeature` and while calling it must be `albumlike-feature`

Comment: sorry not in controller i want to call in my view page ? and also i need to increment the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

On before click u need to defined ur value as `scope.likeCount = 0` and same for unlike too...

And just increment the value by using `+=1`.It will be work for you..

```
angular.module('albumlikeFeature',[]).directive('albumlikeFeature', ['$filter', '$route', function ($filter, $route) {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'app/components/album/albumlikefeature.html',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.likeCount = 0;
        scope.unlikeCount = 0;
        scope.likeClick = function (dataid) {
        scope.likeCount += 1;          
      };

       scope.unlikeClick = function (dataid) {
        scope.unlikeCount += 1;          
      };

    }           
 }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Directive names must follow `camelCase` and so in your directive make changes to name:

```
directive('AlbumlikeFeature',
```

will become

```
directive('albumlikeFeature',
```

Now in your view, refer to it as:

```
<albumlike-feature uniqueid="1" photoid="1"></albumlike-feature>
```

Also your directive function is wrong,

```
templateUrl: 'app/components/album/albumlikefeature.html';

 scope.likeClick = function (dataid) {

            var resultlike = dataid
            console.log(resultlike);
            resultlike.Like = resultlike.Like + 1;               
            scope.likeCount = resultlike.Like;
            scope.unlikeCount = resultlike.Unlike;             
        };
```

You can't have `;` inside the return object also you don't have a `link` function.

```
angular.module('AlbumlikeFeature',[]).directive('albumlikeFeature', ['$filter', '$route', function ($filter, $route) {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'app/components/album/albumlikefeature.html',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.likeClick = function (dataid) {
        var resultlike = dataid
        console.log(resultlike);
        resultlike.Like = resultlike.Like + 1;               
        scope.likeCount = resultlike.Like;
        scope.unlikeCount = resultlike.Unlike;             
      };
    }           
 }
}]);
```

Comment: Good answer/example, however, I would argue it's "good practice" to save `link` for direct DOM manipulation. Perhaps, giving the directive its own controller would be better suited? Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, i agree to that. Just wanted to show what OP is missing

Comment: working like a charm but i have one issue in that i'm getting below error while clicking the like `ReferenceError: likeCount is not defined
    at Scope.scope.likeClick (albumlikefeature.js:15)
    at Parser.functionCall (angular.js:10795)
    at angular.js:19036
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12632)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12730)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:19035)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.n.event.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.n.event.add.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)`

Comment: i have updated my question please check it...and i give upvote too.once u solve my updated questio ill approve the answer